# Should you use if(true) blocks to limit the scope of variables?

Tags: java, memory, scope

In the past I've had to create some enormous methods which could not really be turned into a bunch of smaller methods since it simply wouldn't have made any sense to do so.

Since initializing a lot of variables can be fairly memory-intensive, I've asked myself whether simply using an `if(true)` statement would help reduce the scope in these situations and therefore reduce memory load. It would also improve code quality, because variables wouldn't be accessible elsewhere, when they're no longer needed.

###### Example

```java
if (true) {
    var obj1 = new MyClass(1);
    var obj2 = new MyClass(2);
}
// ...rest of method which does not need obj1 and obj2
```

Is this a good or bad idea?

Comment: Does that honestly seem like readable code to you? Moreover, how do you think that this will reduce memory load?

Comment: Variables would get garbage collected before the method is completely done, which is far better than waiting for the entire method to end and seeing its variables getting garbage collected at that point.

Comment: A simple `obj1 = null` (and a comment) would be much more readable.

Comment: While assigning a variable to null allows garbage collection of the object, it doesn't limit the scope of the variable.  Chances are, you don't want to reuse the variable for anything else, so better to close the scope.  I quite happily use braces as per Sleiman Jneidi's answer, although for me it's always about limiting scope for readability not for garbage collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `if(true)` to reduce the scope of variables.

This would be enough

```
{
    var obj1 = new MyClass(1);
    var obj2 = new MyClass(2);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I seriously didn't even know you could just do that, thanks a lot.